Appearance of svg object in mobile view is different from desktop view


body {
  margin: 0vh 0vw;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12vh;
  background-color: #004d40;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.25vh;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  z-index: 2;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>SVG Header with Half Circle</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <svg width="10vw" height="5vh" viewBox="0 0 100 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M0,0 A50,50 0 0,0 100,0" fill="#004d40" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"/>
    
    </svg>
  </div>

</body>

</html>



Hello, when the svg object goes to mobile view, the svg gets distorted and a gap occurs between the semicircle and the line. Why is this caused and how can we solve it.
on dekstop:

on mobie emulation:

Expected Result:
I was expecting it to look the same on mobile as on desktop.

transform: translate(-50%, 0%); is a rather suboptimal approach but fortunately is not necessary to centre items anymore - is there a reason you're not using flex or grid instead?

No, there was no particular reason, @Dai

Your line has height: 0.25vh while your SVG has a stroke-width="3" - so of course they're going to be different... (and vh should not be used to define a fine line...)

you need to change unit of svg, and adjust size and viewbox

You have width="10vw" height="5vh" and viewBox="0 0 100 50". The size of the svg depends on the size of the window and is not respecting the aspect ratio defined by the viewBox. Different window, different aspect. One possible solution would be removing the height.

By default the SVG is trying to fit and align the lines into the center of the viewBox (or viewport) it is given. You can control this behavior with the preserveAspectRatio attribute on the <svg> element.
In the example below I've used the value xMidYmin meet which translates to:

Align the x axis middle point of the path to the middle point of the view box.
Align the y axis middle point of the path to most upper point of the view box.
Preserve the aspect ratio and make sure everything is visible within the view box. (similar to how background-size: contain works.



body {
  margin: 0vh 0vw;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12vh;
  background-color: #004d40;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.25vh;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  z-index: 2;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>SVG Header with Half Circle</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <svg width="10vw" height="5vh" viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M0,0 A50,50 0 0,0 100,0" fill="#004d40" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"/>
    </svg>
  </div>

</body>

</html>




SVG that is subtly cut also seems to need to be modified.
You have to be sensitive to the use of the unit.
And please check this. It will be helpful.
How to use the <svg> viewBox attribute?


body {
  /* margin: 0vh 0vw; No need unit for zero */
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #004d40;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /* top: calc(50%); No need calc */
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 0.25vh; If you use viewport height, The height of the device changes the thickness of the intended line */
  height: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  z-index: 2;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>SVG Header with Half Circle</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <svg width="100" height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M0,0 A50,50 0 0,0 100,0" fill="#004d40" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"/>
    </svg>
  </div>

</body>

</html>



